# SqlDependency constant database hits

Tags: c#, sql, sqldependency

I have just copied the example from an official Microsoft source http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a52dhwx7(v=vs.80).aspx and I am baffled by it. Having run the application, it makes constant database hits even though nothing is using that table? I thought when that table actually changes the event will fire? I don't want it to make constant DB calls every second, that is awful.

Have I done something wrong? I imagine I have not sure what though. Anybody have a link to a good example preferably not MSDN.

Thanks in advance, Onam.

This is the SQL:

```
return "SELECT [ID],[FromMachine],[FromStore],[FromUser] FROM dbo.Store_Message";
```

As requested, all code:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string connectionString = "server=localhost;database=usicoal;uid=admin;password=";

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetNames();
    }

    private bool DoesUserHavePermission()
    {
        try
        {
            SqlClientPermission clientPermission = new SqlClientPermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted);
            clientPermission.Demand();
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    void dep_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(GetNames));
        }
        else
        {
            GetNames();
        }
        SqlDependency dep = sender as SqlDependency;
        dep.OnChange -= new OnChangeEventHandler(dep_OnChange);
    }

    private void GetNames()
    {
        if (!DoesUserHavePermission())
            return;

        SqlDependency.Stop(connectionString);
        SqlDependency.Start(connectionString);

        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = cn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ID FROM dbo.[BTE_SIMPLE_STORE_MESSAGE]";
                cmd.Notification = null;

                SqlDependency dep = new SqlDependency(cmd);
                dep.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dep_OnChange);

                cn.Open();

                using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[SqlDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx) usually works as you expected it. It fires events if something was changed in your db. Constant calls occure if something is wrong with your query. It's important to use the full two part table name (e.g. dbo.TableName).

The MSDN documentation is not as bad - have a look at this more up-to-date [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62xk7953.aspx) or this [one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9x04ed2.aspx) version.

Comment: I looked at that article however I have SQL Management Studio open on one screen and my app on the other and all it ever does is cycle through and constantly polls the database with the above query. I don't know whether this is correct, to me it seems wrong?

Comment: Are you debugging your code or do you see the querys in the SQL Profiler? If you see the query every second or more frequent in the SQL Profiler => thats definitely wrong. Could you add the corresponding c# code?

Comment: Added the code I am using... under SQL profiler I see the select statement over and over again which makes me think it is not working.

Comment: Oh sweet jesus, its the flaming database that is wonky ARGH! Just created a new database thought it would be a long shot and used same code and it flamin worked! Sweet jesus not sure what is going on but investigating.

Comment: Compatibility level needs to be set at SQL Server 2008(100). Any ideas why it needs to be set at this level?

Comment: Did you restored the db from a backup? Sometimes this leads to a low Compatibility Level. The answer why you need 90 or higher is found here ["Creating a Query for Notification"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181122%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) => see the first "Note"

Answer (score 1):

Found that the above code was fine when I:

- Right click database select properties
- Select options
- Set compatibility level to SQL Server 2008(100)
- OK

Bang the code works correctly.